# MS Update / Dead Battery Workaround on Docked Surface Pro 3

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a Surface Pro 3 which has had a dead battery for about 6 years and since then I've always had it docked. My current version of Windows 10 is no longer supported and I'd like to update but Windows is detecting the battery condition and requires it resolved before proceeding. I've disabled the battery in Device Manager and it's still not letting me through. I've checked the BIOS to see if I could disable Microsoft ACPI and there's no option in there. Surely there is a way to get around this but I'm at my wits end , hopefully someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try downloading the [Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) from Microsoft, using the Media Creation too to put it on USB. This might have the same issue of requiring a battery for installation.
2. Install a new battery, which can be found [for ~US$40](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=surface+pro+3+battery).
3. Consider an alternate operating system. [Windows 10 end-of-life is in 10 months](https://endoflife.date/windows), unless you purchase a [2-year Long Term Service Contract](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2167558-explicit-instructions-for-purchasing-a-windows-10-ltsc-license) (~US$300, if available... and might be only in large quantity). For the Surface Pro 3 to run Windows 11, you'd have to [try a Registry hack](https://ocraz.com/2021/10/15/surface-pro-3-upgrading-to-windows-11/), and then run an unapproved OS.

   Instead, you can download an alternative OS, such as Linux, that should work under *whatever* state the battery is, and would have *continued support*. You could test that  now, *without* having to install the OS, using a bootable USB drive. For example, a [Ubuntu Live USB can be made](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) in perhaps one half hour, and will boot from that USB in a few minutes. If you like the OS, you can then decide to install it to the main drive (again, in a half-hour or so). Ubuntu and many other Linux distros are *free* for individual use, though some corporations pay for technical support, if needed.

Comment: In my experience TPM 1.1 is a hard requirement. Thankfully SP3 supports TPM 2.0.  So, the author should easily be able to bypass the CPU requirement. Bypassing the battery check might be more difficult.  Shocked that check is even happening with Windows Update. Before trying Windows 11 I would try the Upgrade Assistant.

Comment: Regarding #2, while the battery may be cheap the process of trying to open a Surface Pro 3 carries the risk of breaking the screen. It's essentially a glued together tablet with an Intel processor and you have to heat up and pry apart the device and pull the screen away to get near the battery. Because it is quite a large screen it is easier to put just a little too much force in one area and completely crack the glass and immediately making the replacement more expensive. You also have to replace all the glue strips in the process as well.

Comment: For option 1 , I have tried this but not via USB just as an executable , would that make a difference? I will likely go the route of Option 3 as I was considering this before but wasn't sure if it would have the same battery requirement.

Comment: @craigrasmussen, AFAIK, there is no requirement for a charged battery for Ubuntu, as long as the PC works. Let us know here if that works for your use, and mark the answer.

Comment: The issue I'm having now in this process is it's taking me to a Surface System Updating screen before it boots from USB, I've changed the boot order in the BIOS but it appears to be going to this screen before the bootloader?

Comment: Are you following the Surface boot procedure, "press & hold the volume down button, and press & release the power button.?" See also https://surfacetip.com/surface-pro-boot-from-usb/ and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/boot-surface-from-a-usb-device-fe7a7323-8d1d-823d-be17-9aec89c4f9f5